# Как выровнять некоторые <a> по вертикали?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как выровнять некоторые `<a>` по вертикали?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hat">
    <div class="hat_main_block">
        <div class="hat_menu_block">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="../site/src/logo.jpg"></img></a>
            <a>Москва</a>
            <a href="models.html">Модели</a>
            <a href="stocks.html">Акции</a>
            <a href="dealers.html">Дилеры</a>
            <a href="testdrive.html">Тест-драйв</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hat {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.hat_block {
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;

    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.hat_block a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.hat_block a:hover {
    color: #F7761F;
}
```

Получается что картинка LADA находится по центру, а вот слова "Москва", "Модели", "Акции", "Дилеры", "Тест-драйв" - нет. Как же мне добиться того, чтобы эти слова были выравнены по вертикали?
[image: проблема]

Comment: vartical-align: middle

Answer (score 1):

Используйте свойства `display: flex;` и `align-items: center;` для родительского элемента `.hat_menu_block`

Answer (score -1):

Это можно сделать так:

```
.element{
    position: "absolute";  // устанавливаем абсолютное позиционирование
    height: "50%"; // устанавливает высоту 50%. Т.е по центру.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

MaximLensky дал верный ответ! Вот как это можно сделать:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```